# Discord bot level up function doesn't work

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

```
async def xpUp(userId, amount : int):
if str(userId) in usersLvl.keys():
    if usersLvl[userId][0] < ((usersLvl[userId][1]+1)*12):
        usersLvl[userId][0]+= amount
    else :
        usersLvl[userId][1] += 1
        usersLvl[userId][0] -= ((usersLvl[userId][1]+1)*12)

else :
    usersLvl[userId] = [amount, 1]
```

- `usersLvl` is a dictionary that contains users xp and level.
- `usersLvl[userId][0]` is the xp amount of the user and `usersLvl[userId][1]` is their level.

I want the function to verify if the xp amount of the user is higher than the next level multiplied by 12, and if it's true, it should increase the level and substract the xp amount by the xp needed to level up, and if it's false, it should just increase the xp.

However, when I use this function, the xp doesn't increase.

Any idea why?

Comment: In the if statement you cast `userId` to str, but you don't when you increment dictionary value `usersLvl[userId][1] += 1`, this might be the case

Comment: do you have the `@client.command` / `@bot.command` decorator at the top of your function?

Comment: @ilusha Thank you , now it works. It was a very stupid error x) ...